# Is there a detailed manual for Command & Conquer Red Alert for iPhone?

Tags: ios, command-and-conquer-red-alert

Since the in-game guide is very basic and does not answer these questions, I was hoping there was an on-line manual somewhere that described what is going on in more detail, either from EA or someone else. Where can I find a real manual for *Command & Conquer Red Alert* for iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, C&C Red Alert is not a big concern for EA since they bought out and shut down the original company Westwood which created the PC game series Command & Conquer. Luckily they added a virtual manual that was built into the game at the main screen; Tap the square on the right side of the screen with the letter "i" in it. This will provide you with a detailed description on everything you need to know about the game.

Answer (score 0):

EA's documentation for this iOS game is paltry. The only in-depth help re: missions and strategy (not controls) is on **its [C&C Wikia page](http://cnc.wikia.com/wiki/Command_&_Conquer:_Red_Alert_%28iPhone%29)**.

Answer (score 0):

At this link you can read the orginal release of the Red Alert manual-
http://cnc.wikia.com/wiki/File:Red_Alert_1_Manual.pdf

It's old and recommends you use Windows 95 or DOS but the general rules still stand.

Comment: The Red Alert iPhone game isn't Red Alert 1; it's a game based on Red Alert 3.